# Jquery and Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, siblings

I'm having an issue with JQuery and Safari (Windows Version).  The code works on FF/IE7/Chrome but not Safari.

I have a simple `<li>` that has a `<div>` embedded in to - clicking the `<li>` should expose the hidden `div`, but not in Safari.

The HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>something</li>
<li>something2</li>
<li class="more">
        <a href="" class="moreFacetsLink">Click to see more options</a>
        <div class="moreFacets">bunch of text</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JQuery code:

```
     $('.moreFacetsLink').click(function () {

        $(this).siblings('div').toggle();
     });
```

Any thoughts as to what may be going on here?  Again - this seems to work on all other browsers!

I'm a newbie when it comes to JQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How accurate is your HTML pasting?

You never closed your "moreFacetsLink" anchor tag, which probably makes Safari think that it was implicitly closed, and the "bunch of text" is surrounded by an additional, HREF-less Class-less Unclosed anchor tag... evidenced by the fact that this:

```
$(".moreFacetsLink").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings("a").children("div").toggle();
});
```

... does what you want with your submitted markup.

Close off your anchor tag properly (bonus points for including the href attribute) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Sorry - hand typed the above html, i've correct the syntax errors.  The html in my code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

href="" is reloading your page in safari
I would try using css to underline and style it, and drop the empty href.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to `return false;` from the click function to cancel the link click.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if the browser is doing postback and if this is true you can avoid it like this

```
$('.moreFacetsLink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this prevent postback

    $(e.target).siblings('div').toggle();
});
```

try this: `$(e.target)` instead of this `$(this)`

this could be a different way

hope this helps